# Getting SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 1) on Set Global Variable statement

Tags: robotframework

I use a Citrix VM, we have Python 3.7 and Robot 3.1.2.
I have a .robot file for one of my custom keywords to fetch values of elements on a page to individual variables and then set the variable as a global variable so that I can access this variable in other custom keywords. This .robot file contains variables for many elements on a page. When I use this keyword in a test case and execute it, in some runs, the set global variable statements fail with the error - "SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string, line 1"), however, there are many such statements for other similar variables (with the same type of values), works without any error. If I run again, it would show the same error on some different variable. Hence this error is not on the same variables always.
Here is my sample code.

```
***Keywords***

Get Field values:

    ${count}=     get element count    xpath://<locator1>
    ${variable1}=   run keyword if    ${count}>0    get text    xpath://<locator1> 
    convert to string    ${variable1}
    set global variable    ${variable1}

    ${count}=     get element count    xpath://<locator2>
    ${variable2}=   run keyword if    ${count}>0    get text    xpath://<locator2> 
    convert to string    ${variable2}
    set global variable    ${variable2}

    ${count}=     get element count    xpath://<locator3>
    ${variable3}=   run keyword if    ${count}>0    get text    xpath://<locator3> 
    convert to string    ${variable3}
    set global variable    ${variable3}
```

Now if use this keyword in one test case and run it, at times it passes without any error and I can see that variable1, 2, and 3 have values as expected and I can access these variables in other keywords also as those are set as global variables.
Next time if I run, the keyword  - set global variable  ${variable3} fails with the above error and the same statement works for variable 1 and variable 2. In the next run, the same statement might fail for variable 1 and/or variable 2. Please note that all these variable values get values as $amounts only. e.g. $33,600
Now sure why it shows a syntax error for "set global variable $<>" at times and the error is appearing on the random field in each run.

**Failure Screenshot**
[image: Failure Screenshot]

**failed keyword when the variable value is a $ range**[image: failed keyword when the variable value is a $ range]

Comment: I see one issue: you must save converted string variable,``convert to string` does not do anything alone. Try this: `${variable1}=    convert to string    ${variable1}`

Comment: Hello @Pekka , thanks for this input. I updated all applicable lines with above suggestion. Now variables that is having a $ amount range like "$200 - $10,000" are failing with same error while resolving during run time as below.

Comment: `code`${report_avg6Months} = BuiltIn . Convert To String ${report_avg6Months}
Start / End / Elapsed: 20230519 18:51:07.436 / 20230519 18:51:07.437 / 00:00:00.001
18:51:07.437 INFO ${report_avg6Months} = $200 - $99,800

Failed Keyword: BuiltIn . Set Global Variable ${report_avg6Months}
Start / End / Elapsed: 20230519 18:51:07.437 / 20230519 18:51:07.438 / 00:00:00.001
18:51:07.438 FAIL Resolving variable '${200 - $99,800}' failed: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 1) `code`    Please refer the screnshot "failed keyword when variable value is a $ range" in the main question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am running RF 6.0.2, so my errors may differ. However, I was able to reproduce your problem, and it is related to how RF handles variables: [Using variables with keywords creating or accessing variables](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Using%20variables%20with%20keywords%20creating%20or%20accessing%20variables)

Here is how you escape variables with dollar signs:

```
Test Global
    ${report_avg6Months}=            Set Variable    $200 - $99,800
    ${report_avg6Months}=            Convert To String    ${report_avg6Months}
    Run Keyword And Expect Error     Variable '\${200 - $99,800}' not found.
    ...        Set Global Variable   ${report_avg6Months}
    Set Global Variable              \${report_avg6Months}
```

Comment: Hello @Pekka - Thank you for really helping in this matter, Just one Q - What if the variable value is dynamic, I mean the value changes on every run based on my test data on other fields?

Comment: It should work, but you can use the code above to try different values quickly.